# Sort redis cache

Tags: sorting, caching, redis

How can i sort my redis cache.

The data:

```
SADD key '{"id":250,"store_id":3,"url_path":"\/blog\/testblog123123",
"status":"Published","title":"TestBlog123123",
'"description":"","image":null,"description_2":"",
"date":"2017-04-17","blogcategory":"Category 3"}'
```

Next I need to sort my KEY by id.

This works:

```
SORT key BY *->id DESC
```

... but only when:

```
id > 10
```

because redis sort ONLY first number.

Maybe I should use another command to add, but I need JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sorted set from scratch?

```
ZADD key 250 '{"id":250,"store_id":3,"url_path":"\/blog\/testblog123123",
"status":"Published","title":"TestBlog123123",
'"description":"","image":null,"description_2":"",
"date":"2017-04-17","blogcategory":"Category 3"}'
```

I am also not sure why to use Set here at all, because uniqueness of a set element will only be guaranteed for the whole JSON string. And if your JSON serializer changes order of two fields in JSON dict, it will produce another string which is unique again and you'll end up with a dangling old string. Same applies, if you add more fields to the string.